# What is the best practice to use JSP and Ajax to load data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I am a front-end developer who knows little JSP. I am working on a project that is building a CMS. This particular part I need advice is for slideshow data. In the JSP I am loading each slide and then injecting data with ajax. However it seems to be loading slowly, especially slideshows with more than 100 slides. It is also breaking with a lot of slides/HTML structure seems to break.

Each slide's data is loading with it's own endpoint by taking it's ID. In addition, each slide has a edit button that calls the slide's endpoint again to load a form, which also seems to load a bit slow. I was seeking what the best way to go about including this data with ajax. I was thinking something like infinite scroll - specifically http://www.responsivewebmobile.com/app/webroot/rwm_infinite_scroll/. However, what is the best way of organizing this and loading the data? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Single page scrolling.We can load only one page at that time by loading data from Ajax dynamically.
Refer this 
http://pagescroller.com/
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/
While clicking page up or page down or slider ,we can load the content of next page using Ajax with id